# how can I show a 404 page for URL I don't want to have?

Tags: .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I have a website: http://www.immvestwolf.de/
For most websites a 404 page is shown for unknown pages like http://www.immvestwolf.de/ggggggg.
But there is one Section of the website which is build by a plugin. For that section, URLs which don't exist, do not give a 404 header status back.
For example: http://www.immvestwolf.de/expose/39/gggg.  All URLs with "/expose/sometext" don't give a 404 header status back. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: 400 header status?

Comment: sorry, 404 header status...

Answer (score 0):

Any path that hits the plugin is at the descretion of that plugin.So if `../expose` ist the plugin, it is the responsibility of that plugin to decide whether a certain path (within the namespace controlled by the plugin) exists or not.

If the plugin does not care, then you might configure your web server to deny the to-be-non-existant sub-paths. E.g you may have your plugin handle `/expose` but reject any access to `/expose/` or below.

How this is to be achieved depends on what web server you are using and how the plugin expects to be configured.